# HMAC produces different strings in Python3 vs Golang

Tags: python, go, hmac, hmacsha256

I have a Golang function that calculates `hmac` for a given key and challenge. The go code is

```
func get_hmac64(psk string, challenge string) string {
    mac := hmac.New(sha3.New256, []byte(psk))
    mac.Write([]byte(challenge))
    macSum := mac.Sum(nil)
    var macSumB64 = make([]byte, (len(macSum)*8+5)/6)
    base64.URLEncoding.Encode(macSumB64, macSum)
    return string(macSumB64)
}
```

I translated this to Python3 as below.

```
    def get_hmac64(self, psk: str, challenge: str) ->str:
        """
        This generates a different string for same psk and challenge between Golang and Python3
        """
        psk_bytes = bytes(psk, "utf-8")
        challenge_bytes = bytes(challenge, "utf-8")
        mac = hmac.new(psk_bytes, challenge_bytes, hashlib.sha3_256)
        mac_digest = mac.digest()
        b64_encoded = base64.b64decode(mac_digest)
        return b64_encoded.decode("utf-8")
  
    print(get_hmac("abc", "def"))
```

For the python implementation the string returned is `M1P63mj5ytdYUaJJ4m2UMtEKBgRG/K3AzHCW/TjIS1k=` whereas for the `Go` code the generated input for the same key and string is `qWISO-QliNl_dwhDBhkd3MaT`

Shouldnt the value be same if the `key`, `challenge` and the `hash` remains same for the `hmac` implementation across languages? If so, what is the step that I missed in the Python translation?

Comment: The Go code returns a slice of zero bytes.  Use `return base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(macSum)` to return the base64 encoding of the sum.

Comment: @Zombo, sorry that was typo. `Encode` is called, I have updated the code.

Comment: Would you like to share your version of Python? I tried out your python code, remove the self and included necessary libraries, but I went into a runtime Error at the line base64.b64decode(mac_digest)

Comment: What is `NewDragonHash`?

Comment: Ah sorry, Its just glorified wrapper arounf `sha3.New256`. Updated code.

Answer (score 1):

The following code gives the same results as the one you report for your Python code:

```
func get_hmac64(psk string, challenge string) string {
    mac := hmac.New(sha3.New256, []byte(psk))
    mac.Write([]byte(challenge))
    macSum := mac.Sum(nil)
    return base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(macSum)
}
```

(Full code at https://go.dev/play/p/5lWG-jMfELz).
The two differences are that I used `sha3.New256` instead of the strange `NewDragonHash`, and that I fixed the base64 encoding by simply using the `.EncodeToString()` method.